# How to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7?

Tags: installation, wubi

I want to install Ubuntu alongside windows. So I downloaded the `.iso` file, made a bootable USB drive and started the installation.

But when I have to choose how I want to install it, it shows:

```
Install Ubuntu INSIDE Windows 7
Replace  Windows 7 with Ubuntu and
Something else
```

And when I choose to install it *inside Windows* and click the button continue, my PC just restarts and opens Windows. So what am I doing wrong?